# Pyspark crossJoin with specific condition

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark, cross-join

The crossJoin of two dataframes of 5 rows for each one gives a dataframe of `25 rows (5*5)`.
What I want is to do a crossJoin but which is "not full".
For example:

```
df1:                       df2:
+-----+                    +-----+
|index|                    |value|
+-----+                    +-----+
|    0|                    |    A|
|    1|                    |    B|
|    2|                    |    C|
|    3|                    |    D|
|    4|                    |    E|
+-----+                    +-----+
```

The result must be a dataframe of number of rows < 25, while for each row in `index` choosing randomly the number of rows in `value` with which the crossJoin is done.
It will be something like that:

```
+-----+-----+
|index|value|
+-----+-----+
|    0|    D|
|    0|    A|
|    1|    A|
|    1|    D|
|    1|    B|
|    1|    C|
|    2|    A|
|    2|    E|
|    3|    D|
|    4|    A|
|    4|    B|
|    4|    E|
+-----+-----+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample) to get the less number of rows after cross join.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true")
df.join(df1).sample(False,0.6).show()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot